# parsing does not working in android

Tags: android

I am parsing a xml from an url.The url is has mobile IMEI no and searchstring based on my application. i put my xml parsing code in android project it does not work. but if i run as separate java program it is working. please help me.

```
Log.e("rsport-", "function1");
 try{
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
  factory.setCoalescing(true); // Convert CDATA to Text nodes
  factory.setNamespaceAware(false); // No namespaces: this is default
  factory.setValidating(false); // Don't validate DTD: also default
  DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Log.e("rsport-", "function2");
  Document document = parser.parse("http://demo.greatinnovus.com/restingspot/search?userid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&firstname=a&lastname=a");
  Log.e("rsport-","function3"); 
   NodeList sections = document.getElementsByTagName("Searchdata"); 
     int numSections = sections.getLength();
       for (int i = 0; i < numSections; i++) 
     {
       Element section = (Element) sections.item(i); 
       if(section.hasChildNodes()==true){
           NodeList section1=section.getChildNodes();
              for(int j=0;j<section1.getLength();j++){
                if(section1.item(j).hasChildNodes()==true) {
                    for(int k=0;k<section1.item(j).getChildNodes().getLength();k++)                     
                                 xmlvalue=String.valueOf(section1.item(j).getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeValue()).trim();

                                 arl.add(xmlvalue);
                  }
              }
          }
        }

     }
       } 
   catch(Exception e){}
        System.out.println("id"+id+"       searchdatacount"+searchdatacount);
        System.out.println("---------");
        ListIterator<String> litr = arl.listIterator();
        while (litr.hasNext()) {
            String element = litr.next();
            Log.e("rsport-", "elememt");
        }
```

after the `Log.e("rsport-", "function2")`; does not work.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? What is the `logcat` output?

Comment: tell me what error you had got in your Logcat and which tag in your xml you want to parse

Comment: it shows exception is InputSource needs either stream or reader
logcat
04-25 19:01:22.443: ERROR/rsport(2177): {chap=hjdasgdas}
04-25 19:01:22.453: ERROR/listview(2177): android.widget.ListView@43621388
04-25 19:01:22.563: ERROR/rsport-(2177): function1
04-25 19:01:22.563: ERROR/rsport-(2177): function2
04-25 19:01:22.583: ERROR/rsport---(2177): InputSource needs either stream or reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer my blog, i had gave Detailed explanation, http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/parsing-data-from-internet-and-creating.html, and make sure , that you had add the Internet permission in your Manifest file.

If you had gone through Myblog, then you will able to notice that you did the following line as wrong

```
 Document document = parser.parse("http://demo.greatinnovus.com/restingspot/search?userid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&firstname=a&lastname=a");
```

use like this

```
URL url =new URL("http://demo.greatinnovus.com/restingspot/search?userid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&firstname=a&lastname=a");
 Document document= parser.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

Comment: hi sangar ganesh
i got the following in Logcat:
it shows exception is InputSource needs either stream or reader logcat 04-25 19:01:22.443: ERROR/rsport(2177): {chap=hjdasgdas} 04-25 19:01:22.453: ERROR/listview(2177): android.widget.ListView@43621388 04-25 19:01:22.563: ERROR/rsport-(2177): function1 04-25 19:01:22.563: ERROR/rsport-(2177): function2 04-25 19:01:22.583: ERROR/rsport---(2177): InputSource needs either stream or reader